# 403 Forbidden Error when calling Web Api over SSL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssl, asp.net-web-api

I have a standard C# Web Api running on IIS that has a custom AuthorizeAttribute to properly authorize calls via a key in the request header variables. Recently, one of my clients calls to the API over SSL have started to fail with an 403 Forbidden error. He is successful when calling the non-SSL url.

The same call - same url, api key etc. works perfectly over SSL from my machine, and none of my other clients are having any issues with this. What could possibly be the issue for this specific client? I have checked some basic things like his client machine time settings etc. are all in order, not sure if this could be some kind of certificate related issue?

Comment: Did you check whether the key in the request header is present on the server when your client calls the API? Maybe a corporate proxy in the client's company removes custom request headers

Answer (score -1):

try the following:

> 1- check the proxy on his machine

> 2- since **SSL** is used to protect data and safety the data should not change in the way on the server. it could be changed by a virus on the machine (I have the same problem with one of my clients) make sure his system is clean

> 3- consider calling the API in other ways like (postman, browser, ...)

according to what you write clearly, there is something wrong with his machine. if you find the problem It would be nice to tell me too

Comment: Apparently there is no proxy, the calls fail over postman and via their app. I can see the call does hit my app over SSL, but the required header key is missing. But the same call over http works correctly.